# In Grails can the flash storage object only be accessed from controllers and views?

Tags: grails

In Grails the [**`flash`** storage object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html) is used to hold onto [cross request data like messages](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.2%20Controllers%20and%20Scopes).

I know that it can be accessed from most Views and Controllers, but I'm not sure if it's available universally across Grails, or if it can only be accessed from certain conventional objects.

Can the `flash` object be accessed from `Services`, for instance?

Or even anywhere during a live web request?

What are it's precise limitations in terms of access?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can gain access to the `flash` wherever, and more importantly, whenever you have access to a web request. In general, you can get the `flash` from the `GrailsWebRequest` object.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils

def grailsWebRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
// request is the HttpServletRequest
def flash = grailsWebRequest.attributes.getFlashScope(request)
```

If you invoke [`retrieveGrailsWebRequest()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/util/WebUtils.html#retrieveGrailsWebRequest%28%29) outside the context of a web request, you'll get an `IllegalStateException`. The `GrailsWebRequest` is bound to the current thread by a filter, [`GrailsWebRequestFilter`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/index.html?org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequestFilter.html), which is executed early in the service request. So basically, as long as you're in the context of a request and "inside" this filter execution, you should be able to access the flash.

Beyond that, take a look at the source for [`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/1.3.x/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes.java). The flash storage is saved in the session, so theoretically you should be able to use it once you gain access to the session. Be careful though, since it's shared among the different request for the session. The mentioned filter is responsible for advancing the state of the flash throughout requests, essentially popping a `ConcurrentHashMap` from a 2-element queue.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you're within the context of a request you can access the flash scope with

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils

def flashScope = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().flashScope
```

(Grails scripts and Quartz jobs are examples of places in a Grails app that are not within the context of a request)